# Highcharts setData on Columnrange not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Very simple problem, trying to use setData on a columnrange chart, but without success:

Original data:

```
series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [
                [-9.7, 9.4],

            ],
            color: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, CalculateMidColor('#00ff00', '#ff0000', 0.8, 1)],
                    [1, CalculateMidColor('#00ff00', '#ff0000', 0.2, 1)]
                ]
            }
        }]
```

Trying to change the data...

```
chart.series[0].setData([
                [-19.7, 19.4]             
            ],true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4J452/

Have tried multiple variations of arrays etc on the setData, not success - help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are attaching the click event listener before the DOM is ready, so the event is attached to nothing.

You can see this by doing a `console.log`:

```
console.log($('#button'));
$('#button').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].setData([
        [-19.7, 19.4]             
    ],true);
});
```

You'll see that right before attaching the click listener the very same selector is an empty array (check your console in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4J452/2/)).

To solve this you could simply move your button-click code inside the `$(function() { ... })`, which is a jQuery shorthand for "[document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)". Like so:

```
$(function () {
    ...

    console.log($('#button'));
    $('#button').click(function() {
        chart.series[0].setData([
            [-19.7, 19.4]             
        ],true);
    });
});
```

As in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4J452/3/). You can also check your console here to see the different output.

In sum, your chart and the `setData` function were working perfectly, but the button was just not executing the code to update your chart.